# A semi transparent overlay with a button and a label?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm trying to achieve something similar to the attached image - simply a semi-transparent overlay and a label and a button. I have tried adding a view with a button and a label and decreasing the alpha but I can't get it to work. Does anyone know how I could achieve something similar while trying to be cheap on memory.

[image]

Thank you in advance for any help :).

Comment: How are you displaying the transparent view? If you're presenting it modally then I think your best bit is to take a screenshot of the background, then use it as an image for a UIImageView, which would be your modal view's background.

Comment: You should be able to do that? What's the issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, adding a subview with semi-transparent background color worked perfectly fine for me:

[image: Semi-trasparent view]

The only code I added to the single-view app template:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    [self.view addSubview:self.semiView];
}
```

Comment: How did you do that? Sorry I was so late replying had to do the washing up :)

Comment: Just like that – created a view in the same XIB, reduced its background colour alpha to 70%, added an `UIView` outlet to the view controller using the Assistant editor and then invoked `addSubview:` on the view controller's view with the new view as the argument (see the code part in the answer). TL;DR just use `addSubview:` to make the semi-transparent view visible. Use the subview's `removeFromSuperview` to remove it when you don't it anymore.

Comment: How do I identify my view as the semi-transparent one?

Comment: I'm not following, sorry. You should be able to make any UIView semi-transparent by setting it's background colour to a value with a less than 100% alpha. Also make sure the view's  `opaque` property is set to `NO`.

Comment: [self.view addSubview:self.semiView]; - X-code says property of semiView not found on object of type - not sure how to fix this?

Comment: Turn on the Assistant editor in Xcode, control-drag your overlay view somewhere inside your view controller class definition (`.h` file). When a callout appears, name your outlet `semiView`. For more info on creating outlets using Interface Builder see [Edit User Interfaces](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/ToolsLanguages/Conceptual/Xcode_User_Guide/030-Edit_User_Interfaces/edit_user_interface.html) ("Manage Connections Between User Interface Objects" section).

Comment: Oh, I dragged it over to file's owner not to the header file, thank you so much :)

Comment: Sorry to bother you again, but it's not quite working as intended. I have a button on my main view that says 'Well Done' when that is pressed it is supposed to then add the view as a sub view and when continue is pressed on the semiView view it is then supposed to remove from superview. Instead it adds to subview straight away and then when continue is cleared suddenly my toolbar is missing. I can screen shot if you would like. Thank you, sorry to be so awful:/.

Comment: You aren't adding the subview in `viewDidLoad`, are you? In any case you shouldn't, add an action for the 'Well Done' button and add the subview in that action handler. Not sure what's going on with the toolbar.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/27700/discussion-between-caroline-and-zrxq)